# Error Setting Document Element in VBA Code Referencing XML

Tags: xml, vba, dom

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568074/inserting-a-unique-id-in-specific-row-locations-for-multiple-ids) I was looking to find a way to manipulate XML, and an answer was provided by David that looked very promising.  However, I have been having a small issue when it comes to the following line:

```
Set Entity = DOM.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("EntityId")(0)
```

where by EntityId I actually meant entityId (to preserve continuity I have left the code as is).

Namely I get the following error: Object variable / with block variable not set.

Now, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413004/vba-pull-xml-data-to-excel), which outlined a potential solution, but I have the MSXML 6.0 reference box checked.  I have also confirmed, as that poster did, that the tag does exist in the XML document I am referencing.  Is there another reason this could be happening outside of user error?

EDIT: Screenshot of entityId:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can replicate your error is by making an XML file which is invalid/doesn't parse.

Your XML file is broken.  Fix it, and the code will work.

Put a breakpoint on the `Set entity` line, and then examin the `DOM.parseError` in the Locals window.

[image]

This will indicate whether there are problems with your XML file that prevent it from parsing.

When the xml file cannot be parsed, the `DOM.DocumentElement` is `Nothing`, and that will raise the `Object Required` error.

Comment: Unfortunately parseError shows errorCode 0, and documentElement contains child nodes.  However, documentElement does describe 'definition' as 'Nothing' - could that be the issue?

Comment: Hmm I don't think that's ir but can you add a screenshot showing that?   And you could try skipping to the lines to print the new file without making any "changes" I would be curious to see whether it will print the xml before any changes...

Comment: It's OK if the definition is "nothing" (that's what I see too), but the object itself is not `Nothing`. If you see there are child nodes to the `DocumentElement`, first step to troubleshoot would be to start picking through those and see where they take you -- can you navigate through that tree and find the "entityID" node(s)?

Comment: I found entityId under a child node - I'll update my post with a screenshot.

Comment: Are you still doing `Set Entity = DOM.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("EntityId")(0)`???

Comment: No, I revised to entityId (and entity) but left the original code with an explanation since Tim pointed out the EntityId issue and it would make that comment confusing if I modified the code in the question.

Comment: Yeah that should not matter... I don't suppose there's any way you can send the file to me? Without the file, it's really impossible to assist any further.

Comment: It should be possible to send the sample XML file that I am using at some point.